# How to continuously stream data to the client in rxjava?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rx-java, observable

Consider a situation where I have an infinite `Stream` (**java.util.stream.Stream**) of data on the server as follows.

```
Stream.iterate(0,k-> k++);
```

I need a way, so that I can have a client which can subscribe to this stream and read it's contents using `rx.Observable`.

I did try to return an `Observable` from the Controller on the server side, but I get the following Exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type : class rx.Observable`

Project Setup:

1. Server and client are Spring Boot applications
2. Marshalling and Unmarshalling is done using jackson-databind

Specific questions:

1. What am I missing? (topics to read)
2. Is there a way to marshal the `Observable` using any other api?

**P.S.**
I need a setup where the client can actively subscribe and unsubscribe to the server. 
Please feel free to suggest edits to make the question better as I am new to ***Reactive programming***.

Comment: that is only supported in Spring 5 and thus Spring Boot 2.0.0. Both of which aren't final yet. Also a `Stream` isn't reactive you would need one of the reactive components for that (a `Flux` from Reactive for instance or `Observable`).

Comment: is there another way to do this in java?
I mean still using the rx.Obserevable

Comment: You would have to do everything manually, prior to Spring 5 there is no reactive support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution to my question by following [Spring Tips: the Spring Web Flux Reactive Client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leZdgr-O4LE)

Since, there is no javadoc available (yet) for the new **WebFlux** component of **Spring 5** as it is not finalized yet (mentioned by  M. Deinum, in his comments), it is not really possible to get to a proper solution unless someone is patient enough to play around with the different methods provided by various classes.

Following links can be used for further viewing and references:
[WebFlux Framework- spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#web-reactive)
[Spring Tips: Functional Reactive Endpoints with Spring Framework 5.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjrAmhlTjug)

**P.S.**
Please feel free to edit and update the answer, if you find better links and tutorials.